# which numbers will print out from this JS function?

Tags: javascript

trying to understand it and trying to solve some questions online, and came across this:

```
(function (){
console.log({"question": 9});

[5,4,3,2,100,15,30,45,74,25,32]
      .filter(e => 0)
      .forEach(e => console.log({e}))


}) ();
```

I'm trying to see if something will actually print out from this code below? 
possible answers:

1. all numbers greater than 5
2. all numbers
3. all numbers less than 5
4. none of the above ?? I said none of the above, what do u think ?

Comment: just copy&paste in devtool and run it yourself.

Comment: did that and didn't print out any numbers, it gave me __proto__: Object

Comment: that's from console.log({"question": 9})

Comment: yes, so then how in devtoold can I see which numbers will run ?!!

Comment: if it doesn't print anything when you run it then it doesn't print anything.

Comment: u think so, ?  so the answer would be none of the above ?

Comment: the filter callback function returns 0, which is falsy, so the filtered array will always be empty, that's why it will never print anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
[5,4,3,2,100,15,30,45,74,25,32]
      .filter(e => 0)
```

This says to take the array, and filter out any values that are equal to 0.  None of the values are equal to 0, so this returns an empty array

```
[]
```

`.forEach()` on an empty array will return undefined, as there is nothing to iterate over.  That is why this is returning an undefined value.  If you want to test things out, try this:

```
[5,4,3,2,100,15,30,45,74,25,32]
      .filter(e => e > 50)
```

This will return the values of the array that are over 50.  Then your last `console.log` statement will work.

Hope that clears things up for you.